# Cisco IOS: Limiting internet bandwidth usage for specific VLAN

Tags: cisco, vlan, qos, bandwidth

I would like to limit the usage of a 10 MBit internet connection for a specific internal VLAN to 2 MByte (on a Cisco router, IOS 15.3).

Is that possible in general?

How can the router make sure that the incoming/returning traffic from the internet destined to that VLAN will not exceed the desired rate? I.e. if a server is sending back (i.e. file transfers) with a very high rate? Of course the router could just drop everyhting which exceeds the desired rate, but isn´t it too late at that stage, because the WAN link would already been saturated?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes it is feasible. You may want to lookup Cisco QOS - rate limiting on an svi  interface.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have limited control over traffic coming into your network. By the time you see the traffic, the bandwidth has been used. At that point, all you can do is to police it.

If the traffic is in TCP connections, loss of traffic will result in retransmission requests that should cause the sender to slow, but it is an inexact way to do it.